# How to enable Front audio port (headphone jack) in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: sound, audio-jack

In ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit, the rear headphone port in CPU is working well, But the front headphone ports are not working, We tried a lot of methods which is gathered from the internet. What is the exact procedure to enable the front headphone port for audio output? I am sure that, there is no hardware failure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sudo apt-get install pavucontrol

open - PulseAudio Volume Control.

tap - Configuration tab.

Select profile - Analog Stereo Duplex (unplugged).

tap - Output Devices.

Select Port - Headphones (unplugged).

Comment: Hi @Kathir, thanks for the comment, this works. If I unplug front port and plug rear port, and plug the front port again, the sound gone. Gotta re-config. You figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

In the BIOS in audio controller that was in auto I put it in *Enable*, and then in the Alsa mixer I selected the Intel sound card and scrolling with the arrows I looked for the last element and changed the option to *Headphones*.